# HTML5 File Upload Hangs in iOS Safari Mobile

Tags: ajax, html, file-upload, mobile-safari

I have a basic HTML5 file upload script using `$.ajax()` (I've also tried with a vanilla `xhr`) that uploads an image to imgur.com. It works great on the desktop, and uploads properly on iOS Safari, but on iOS Safari it seems to 'hang' when it's finished uploading - the loading indicator at the top of the phone continues spinning indefinitely. Any idea what might be causing this?

http://jsfiddle.net/AFLNe/

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add error handling to your response to inspect to see if there are any errors being passed back:

```
     ..
    ,success: function(response) {
            console.log("Success", response);
            $("body").append("<a href=\"" + response.data.link + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + response.data.link + "</a><br>");
        }
     ,error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Status:"+ textStatus +","+ errorThrown);
    }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but if error() were called, how would success() have been called?

Comment: Sorry, I neglected the fact it was going down the success path.  I guess given that setting up a _timeout_ section in your ajax request would probably be a wasted effort too.  Have you considered that jsfiddle may be the culprit for the spinning bar? Or have you ruled that out?

Comment: I wish :/ I tried it locally first - just used jsfiddle for the demo here